# Stuck on detecting file system

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia

I'm stuck on "Installing file system" and I even tried clicking the try ubuntu button but everything just freezes (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). My specs:
i5-8300H
Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050ti 4gb
8gb ram
256gb SSD
1TB HDD

I am installing Ubuntu on my HDD with 100gb of its partition, with bootloader installer selected as my SSD in which Windows 10 is installed

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by using nomodeset parameter, I gave instructions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245974/installer-freezes-randomly-mouse-stops-moving-ubuntu-not-installing) question asked by me on fixing everything.