# Installer freezes randomly, mouse stops moving, ubuntu not installing

Tags: dual-boot, freeze

I haven an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52 with i5-8300H processor, GTX 1050ti 4gb and 8gb of ram, so what happens is whenever I try to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, during the installation setup, the mouse freezes randomly and I have to use keyboard to select options and sometimes the whole setup freezes at create partition (in something else option). I tried installing several times but it keeps freezing, I also tried the Try Ubuntu option but it froze again. I have a UEFI system to I double checked that I have ACHI instead of RTS in BIOS menu but nothing helps. Is this a problem with the Nvidia card? I have checked the 3rd party software option while installing though.

I am trying to dual boot with Windows 10 which is my SSD and there is an unallocated partition of 100GB of my 1TB HDD, bootloader installer is selected as my 256GB SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to know the cause of the problem and fixed it too. This all was happening because of the Nvidia card that I have, and to fix it, I simply added nomodeset parameter before install. More info here: https://medium.com/@peterpang_84917/personal-experience-of-installing-ubuntu-18-04-lts-on-xps-15-9570-3e53b6cfeefe

Adding nomodeset parameter:
 1. Boot with your USB
 2. Now you will see 3-4 options with `*Ubuntu` option as the first option
 3. Now highlight `*Ubuntu` and click e, and add `nomodeset` after the words `quiet splash`
 4. Press F10 and install Ubuntu as you would do it.

You can install Nvidia drivers as you boot into the system and open the `Software & Updates` app.

Once this is done follow 2nd step again and now instead of `nomodeset` add `nouveau.modeset=0`
And finally when you boot into the system:
 1. Open the terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
 2. Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"`.
 3. Press save and close the window
 4. Finally run `sudo update-grub2`
 5. Profit!

Comment: Please share key part of the solution as the link might anytime be removed.

Comment: The key part was actually using the nomodeset parameter, I will add steps on how to do that right now